# Excel - How to apply a filter accross multiple cell ranges

Tags: excel

I am trying to sort A-Z a range of cells that are not in sequence.  The 3 cell ranges are as follows

B5:C31

F5:G31

J5:K31

Any ideas?

example:

[image]

Comment: Well as an explanation you can simply use the sort function to sort each set of columns alphabetically, but then you are left with people with the surname beginning with D grouped alphabetically in column one and then another group of people with the letter D in colum 2.  I would like all the D's moved together in one colum and then overlapping to the next colum when there are too many.  This is so that the total list remains in view but in alphabetical order and makes use of the screen horizontally instead of having to scroll down.  Its like the equivalent of a text wrap I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Macro:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fg As String
Dim ee As Integer
Dim Dime(1 To 3) As Integer

Fg = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Tmp"
ee = 1
For i = 1 To 3
    Sheets(Fg).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Col" & i & "Ran").Copy
    Dime(i) = Range("Col" & i & "Ran").Rows.Count
    Sheets("Tmp").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ee = ee + Dime(i)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ee).Select
    Sheets(Fg).Select
Next
Sheets("Tmp").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tmp").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tmp").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B" & ee)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ee = 1
For i = 1 To 3
    Sheets("Tmp").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ee & ":B" & (ee + Dime(i) - 1)).Copy
    Sheets(Fg).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Col" & i & "Ran").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ee = ee + Dime(i)
Next
Sheets("Tmp").Delete
```

Copy all the column (Range named Col1Ran, Col2Ran, Col3Ran) in a temp sheet -> Sort -> Rebuild ...
You need to adapt the code to your column... The sample use 2 column.